# What should be filled in "Honoring", "Given by" and "R.S.V.P"

Tags: meaning

In the invitation letters, what should I fill in to the fields "Honoring", "Given by" and "R.S.V.P"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Honoring* describes who the event will honor.  (For a wedding invitation, it would be the name of the bride and groom).

*Given by* describes who is hosting the event.  (For a wedding, it's often the parents of the bride or groom).

*RSVP* would describe how the people invited should respond, saying whether or not they plan to attend.  In the case where an invitation is sent with a postage-paid reply card, this might simply be a no later than date (e.g., by May 11, 2012).  For a more informal party, it might have a phone number or email address instead.

Answer (score 1):

"Honoring": The subject of the occasion and event. E.g. The Birthday Boy

"Given by" : The person hosting the event Eg. The Mother

["R.V.S.P."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSVP_%28invitations%29) means to reply as soon as possible, except it's a French word, so the initials don't correspond to English:

> RSVP or Rsvp (or either of these with a period inserted after each letter) is a request for a response from the invited person. It is an initialism derived from the French phrase **répondez s'il vous plaît**, meaning "Please respond if it pleases you."

Comment: ...so you do not put anything  next to  *RSVP*, just leave it at the end as a request to the addressee.  (By the way *please, if it pleases you*, is as tautologous in French as in English)

Comment: On this form, the "RSVP" field is for the address to which invitees should send their response.